# Using a String to point to a certain list ( or Array )

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say if I have a user input any word they want and I want to save that word to an Array named the first letter of the word they enter. I already initialize these Arrays ( a - z ). So when a user enters for example:

"Apple" and gets saved as word, then I do .substring(0,1).toLowerCase(); and save that as String Letter. How do I go about basically doing Letter.add(word);

At the moment I have 26 if statements and there MUST be an easier way of doing this.

Thank you.

Edit:
What I have now is an ArrayList of ArrayLists because it was what our teacher wanted. I called the first Array List, and then the Arrays inside that are named a - z. In one of my methods I want to delete an entry by name. deleteEntry ( String name ). I then get the first letter of that name and put it to lowercase. Then I dont know how I can just do [firstLetter].remove(x) (where x is index of name)

Basically is it possible to do this.

(String).add(Another String);

where the String can only be a letter of the english alphabet.

Comment: ma y  we see your code ;)

Comment: you have the word String word, and the letter. Perhaps you could use a swich-case (case "a": etc)

Comment: You should really post some more code if you want a more precise answer. I don't think it's clear what you have already and what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `Map<Character, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Define an array `arr` of `ArrayList`s of `String`s and index this
array from 0 to say 255. The char type can be converted up to int
so you can use char as index of your array.

So just do `arr[firstLetter].add(word)` where
`firstLetter` is the char `word.charAt(0)`.

Comment: What I have now is an ArrayList of ArrayLists because it was what our teacher wanted. I called the first Array List, and then the Arrays inside that are named a - z. In one of my methods I want to delete an entry by name. deleteEntry ( String name ). I then get the first letter of that name and put it to lowercase. Then I dont know how I can just do [firstLetter].remove(x) (where x is index of name)